# Google Charts Update Category Filter based on other Category Filter

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have these two filters below, both are implemented into google charts. When I change **filter1**, the data changes in the visualization, but the values in **filter2** do not change. I was wondering if that was possible with Google Charts.

- filter1 has: 1 and 2 for options
- filter2 has: A,B,C,D,E,F for options

Selecting 1 from **filter1** needs to trigger the data-source of **filter2** to filter to A,B,C.

Selecting 2 from **filter1** needs to trigger the data-source of **filter2** to filter to D,E,F.

Filters for google charts:

```
var filter_1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
                'containerId': 'filter1',
                'options': {
                    'filterColumnIndex': 0,
                    'ui': {
                    'allowTyping': false,
                    'allowMultiple': false,
                    'selectedValuesLayout': 'belowStacked',
                    'label': 'Filter 1:'
                }
                }
            });


var filter_2= new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
            'containerId': 'filter2',
            'options': {
                'filterColumnIndex': 1,
                'ui': {
                'allowTyping': false,
                'allowMultiple': false,
                'selectedValuesLayout': 'belowStacked',
                'label': 'Filter 2:'
            }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bind(filter_1, filter_2)
```

This will make any filter_2 change its options based on filter_1. Change the order to have the reverse effect. Once that is done, to get both filters to your chart...

```
bind([filter_1, filter_2], chart)
draw(chart)
```